# autoGenerate="false" is ignored in datastore-indexes.xml

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I've deleted datastore-indexes-auto.xml and local_db.bin, set autoGenerate="false" in  in datastore-indexes.xml, and restarted the dev server.  Still, it persists in automatically generating indexes and writing them to datastore-indexes-auto.xml.

I'm using appengine 1.4.3 for Java with the latest google plugin for eclipse.

Any secrets I need to know about to get the dev server to throw an exception instead of silently creating the index?

Comment: Me too. No idea. This is quite bad for testing, because you can't tell whether it's going to fail on production until you do it.

Comment: Actually, it turns out I was calling the file datastore-indices.xml rather than datastore-indexes.xml. Are you sure you called the file exactly right? It should be in war/WEB-INF/datastore-indexes.xml -- not in appengine-generated.

Comment: Ah hah! I _was_ using the file under appengine-generated.  Post that as an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem, and it turns out I was calling the file `datastore-indices.xml`, rather than `datastore-indexes.xml`. Are you sure you called the file exactly right? It should be in `war/WEB-INF/datastore-indexes.xml` -- not in `appengine-generated`.

It took awhile to find the documentation on this -- it's under "Configuration" -- [Datastore Index Configuration](https://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig.html).